# Cannot GET , nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I tired to solve this problem, when I browse `localhost:5000` I got error like

> Cannot GET /

```js
//*****************app.js************ 
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const v1 = require('./routes/v1');
// ************* DB Config *************//
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URL, {

    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected' , () => {
console.log('Connected to the databse');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error' , (err) => {
    console.error('Failed to connected to the databse: ${err}');
    });




//**************Midlewares ***********//
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
//*************Routes *****************//
app.use('/api/v1', v1);
module.exports = app ;
```

```js
//**********  index.js ***************//

require('dotenv').config();
const app = require('./src/app')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log('Server is ready for connections on port ${PORT}');

});
```

Comment: I would strongly recommended you to learn the basics of Express.js framework before you go any further. You haven't defined any handler for the root route **/** and once you learn the basics you will be able to fix the error yourself.

Answer (score -1):

the problem here is you have no route at the root /
you have to add either your routes you defined or define a root route